# Get parent/child or parent/siblings depending on the ID passed

Tags: mysql, query

This is similar to my table:

```
| id | parent_id | title        |
|----|-----------|--------------|
| 61 | NULL      | title of 61  |
| 62 | 61        | another title|
| 68 | 61        | more text    |
| 75 | 61        | testing 123  |
```

Let's say I select ID 61. I want this output (all children of parent):

```
| id | title        |
|----|--------------|
| 62 | another title|
| 68 | more text    |
| 75 | testing 123  |
```

so, i use the following mysql:

```
SELECT a2.id, a2.title
FROM article a
JOIN article a2 ON a2.parent_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 61
```

...so far so good...

Let's say I select ID 75, I want this output (parent and siblings):

```
| id | title        |
|----|--------------|
| 61 | title of 61  |
| 62 | another title|
| 68 | more text    |
```

so, i use this query:

```
SELECT a2.id, a2.title
FROM article a
JOIN article a2 ON COALESCE(a2.parent_id, a2.id) = a.parent_id
WHERE a.id = 75 AND a2.id != 75
```

Is there a way to create a combination of those 2 queries so whatever ID i pass, it will output correctly...

NOTE:
English is not my first language, please feel free to ask questions if its not clear

Comment: So you always want parent, siblings and children?

Comment: @Lennart Basically, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT a2.id, a2.title 
FROM article a2
WHERE a2.parentid = 61
```

To combine this with your second query you can use union:

```
SELECT a2.id, a2.title 
FROM article a 
JOIN article a2 
    ON COALESCE(a2.parent_id, a2.id) = a.parent_id 
WHERE a.id = 61 AND a2.id <> 61

UNION

SELECT a2.id, a2.title 
FROM article a2
WHERE a2.parentid = 61;
```